# What program could you use to gather people together like Skype?

Tags: windows, gratis, cross-platform, chat

The program, Skype, is not conducive to hold large amounts of connections for chat conferences.  No video.

I'm running into an issue and need a program that can support 100+ connections without crashing as a replacement to Skype.

I only want voice talking on this, I don't want video or text.

I have four recommendations so far, Whats Up, [Tango](http://www2.tango.me/), [TeamSpeak](http://www.teamspeak.com/), and Ventrillo.

---

I went to TeamSpeak and have learned a lot.  Apparently, you can't have third party servers host for you for free unless you are a non-profit.

1. I don't know how to set up my computer as a server.
2. I'd like it to be free
3. One time use for 1 hour
4. All platforms supported, but if that isn't possible then Windows XP and up.

I have Windows 7 (but not Windows Server).

Comment: voice only.  I don't want video and no texting.  I don't want people complaining that they can't connect and they are dropping out all the time.  I don't want to be spending my time doing administrative things for it vs. using it for the meeting I need it for.

Comment: Thank you.  And thank you for leading me to this site.  I didn't know about it.  I've used Super User for my Windows Server class.

Comment: Ok.  I thought they looked the same as if ran by the same group.  Now I patiently wait.  I have four recommendations so far, Whats Up, Tango, TeamSpeak, and Ventrillo.

Comment: What operating system(s) must be supported by the clients? Must it be free (application & service), or what's the budget?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is lacking sufficient information required to answer as per the requirements

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is an audio conferencing solution. If you're in the US, you can use http://www.freeconferencecalling.com/free-conferencing.html:

- free
- it supports up to 1,000 callers in a single conference call with up to 25 callers able to speak at any given time.
- conference calls are limited to 6 hours per single call.
- the conference can be recorded.
- not restricted to phone: most popular VOIP services like Skype can be used to call.

Comment: Thank you.  So this is by phone and not by computer?

Comment: @user3300 not restricted to phone: most popular VOIP services like Skype can be used to call.